# How to hide light-colored wires in a dark-colored cabinet?

Tags: wiring, ducts

I'm installing some LED lights in a particle-board cabinet. The cabinet's walls have dark-colored veneers (nearly black), while the wires to the LEDs are beige, and would stand out quite prominently.

Routing the wires on the other side of the walls is not an option.

Cable raceways I see are all way large and also light-colored.

I probably could use thin dark-colored PVC tubes of some sort, but I'm not sure how to attach them to the walls of the cabinet neatly enough.

Painting the wires black might be the last resort :) I still hope there's a better solution. Is there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's stick-on wire chases that can be purchased.  I think the usual big box hardware stores carry them.  Slide the wire inside, peel off the sticky, and bury it in a corner.  You won't see it.

Google plastic raceway cable organizers.  The first one that came up says it was available in black or ivory.  http://cableorganizer.com/economical-latching-raceway/

Comment: Thanks! These guys actually have black raceways only 11mm thick, this must fit the bill.

Answer (score 3):

There are many cable-wrapping solutions.  My first suggestion would be small heat-shrink tubing.  This would hold multiple wires together, and color them black.  small split loom could accomplish the same thing, although it would look very different if any light shone into the cabinet.  Ultimately, you could simply wrap the wires in electrical tape, although that would be a pain.  I'd avoid paint, as it's likely to start flaking after a few years.

You could also replace the wire.  You'd need to take the fixtures at least partially apart, but it's likely not terribly difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if it would be possible to dye the wires a darker color?  Makezine featured methods for doing this some time ago http://blog.makezine.com/2009/07/18/how-to-dye-computer-parts/